# Javascript based image editing tool canvas or SVG

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I am building a javascript based image editing tool. Currently, I am using Canvas for this, but at times I am getting the feeling that, my path is full of undocumented stuff and random hacks. And I still haven't figured out many things, such as how to allow user to type in canvas? How to detect drawn objects on canvas and allow user to move them?

In the meanwhile, I was looking at SVG for similar stuff, and [SVG Edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html) seems like the thing I want (Except I will have to do lot of customization before I will be able to use it, which isn't necessarily bad).

So my question, which tool is more mature for building this stuff, considering IE support is not a priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do different things. Things drawn to the canvas aren't "moveable" since they aren't objects, just pixels. On the other hand, SVG doesn't allow you to draw in pixels by reasonable means.

I think that this white paper is an incredible resource for anybody planning on or getting into working with Canvas and SVG for editing purposes. It gives a fantastic perspective of what the playing field looks like.

http://www.svgopen.org/2009/papers/54-SVG_vs_Canvas_on_Trivial_Drawing_Application/

From the paper:

> In this paper we will create a small
>   vector drawing application with SVG,
>   and a small pixel drawing application
>   with Canvas. Then we will swap
>   platforms: we'll create a pixel
>   drawing application with SVG, and a
>   vector drawing application with
>   Canvas. This experiment gives useful
>   info on the limits of both techniques.